# Clear Range from another workbook using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, delete-row

I have a workbook (Generator) that pulls Google form response data from another workbook (Responses). Originally the form data went to sheets that were in the Generator workbook. However, to simplify the Generator workbook and speed up other script files, I now have the form responses going to their own separate workbook (Responses). That data needs to be "refreshed" for each user, which originally was done using UI button that triggered the .deleteRows when the worksheets were all in the same workbook.  However, now that they're in separate workbooks, I'm not sure how to get the .deleteRows to reference the new workbook (Responses). I've put my original code below, which works exactly as I need it to when all the sheets are in the same workbook. The clearContent functions don't need to be touched, those are referencing the sheet with additional UI data and the sheet where the script is triggered.  If anyone can point me in the right direction for how to get it to reference the new workbook (Responses) I'd really appreciate it. Thanks

```
function clearRange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var Trench = ss.getSheetByName("Trenching");
  var Pressure = ss.getSheetByName("Pressure");
  var Falls = ss.getSheetByName("Falls");
  var Chemical = ss.getSheetByName("Chemical");
  var Confined = ss.getSheetByName("Confined");
  var LOTO = ss.getSheetByName("LOTO");
  var Rigging = ss.getSheetByName("Rigging");
  var Heavy = ss.getSheetByName("Heavy");
  var Hot= ss.getSheetByName("Hot");
  var Pipe= ss.getSheetByName("Pipe")

  Trench.deleteRows(2, 5);
  Pressure.deleteRows(2, 5);
  Falls.deleteRows(2, 5);
  Chemical.deleteRows(2, 5);
  Confined.deleteRows(2, 5);
  LOTO.deleteRows(2, 5);
  Rigging.deleteRows(2, 5);
  Heavy.deleteRows(2, 5);
  Hot.deleteRows(2,5);
  Pipe.deleteRows(2,5);

 var data1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("B3:B6").clearContent()
 var data2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("J3:J7").clearContent()
 var data3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("J9").clearContent()
 var data4 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("E8:F10").clearContent()
 var data5 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("A13:A133").clearContent()
 var data6 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("G13:G136").clearContent()
 var data7 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("I13:I136").clearContent()
 var data8 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("K13:K136").clearContent()
 var data6 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("L13:L136").clearContent()

}
```

Comment: You need to simplify your problem, this site is for specific programming issues not projects, edit your question and give sample data with the most simple demonstration of what the BEFORE and AFTER should look like plus your current attempt. Your question will probably be closed pretty fast if you don’t do this.

Comment: Simplify it how exactly? I have a UI button on a worksheet and I need it to delete rows from sheets on another workbook. I can get the row references etc..., I just can't figure out how to reference the NEW workbook.  I posted my original code to show that I've already written something that works when the sheets were in a single workbook, and that I'm not just fishing to get someone else to write the code for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Clear ranges from another Spreadsheet

```
function clearAnotherSpreadsheet(id="11yNxdh_GIokeHIctdzt3LDKVm7rYIJvAPlMLzunn7zE") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rl = sh.getRangeList(["B3:B6", "J3:J7", "J9", "E8:F10", "A13:A133", "G13:G136", "I13:I136", "K13:K136", "L13:L136"]);
  rl.getRanges().forEach(rg => rg.clearContent())
}
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, this was perfect, sent me right down the path I needed. I had to change things a little bit since the response workbook has SEVERAL worksheets, but I was able to figure out those references easily enough.  Didn't know I could use the function name to reference another workbook ID like you did, I'll have to look into that more and see if that'll help simplify some of my other projects.  Really appreciate the help.